# Connecting Ashtech antenna to mobile device

Tags: antenna, gps, gnss

Just recently I got my hands on some old GNSS survey equipment from Ashtech, which was originally brought to the market around 2010.

It consists of two ASH111660 antennas with corresponding two Ashtech Promark 100 devices, each connected by TNC/m LEM/m cables.  They were used in a rover/base configuration.

My problem now is that the handheld Promark 100 devices are quite worn down (e.g. very bad batteries,) are no longer supported nor updated, there is no option to expand licenses, etc.

I would like to discard them and ideally just use the two antennas as external GPS antennas on my smartphone (or other suitable and affordable modern mobile device.)

On the software side this does not seem to be much of a problem, but first I must find a way to physically connect an antenna (TNC-f) to another mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antennas are most likely ‘active’ in that there is amplifier circuitry in them. This needs a dc injector and a power source for them to operate. With the extra cost and fiddling around you might want to reconsider what you had in mind........